# How to reach first member of List<yourDrawAction>?

Tags: c#, winforms, list

```
class DrawAction
{
    public Rectangle Dortgen { get; set; }
    public Brush Firca { get; set; }
    public PointF Koordinat { get; set; }
    public DrawAction(Brush color_, Rectangle rect_ )
    { Dortgen = rect_; Firca = color_; }
    public DrawAction(Brush color_)
    { Firca = color_; }
    public DrawAction (PointF k_)
    { Koordinat = k_; }
}
       n1 = new PointF(Start.X, Start.Y - (Start.X - End.X) * 173 / 100 * 2 / 3);
       n2 = new PointF(Start.X + (Start.X - End.X), Start.Y + (Start.X - End.X) * 173 / 100 * 1 / 3);
       n3 = new PointF(Start.X - (Start.X - End.X), Start.Y + (Start.X - End.X) * 173 / 100 * 1 / 3);
    ucgen.Add(new DrawAction(n1));
    ucgen.Add(new DrawAction(n2)); 
    ucgen.Add(new DrawAction(n3));
    List<DrawAction> ucgen = new List<DrawAction>();
```

Here is some of my code. I list the points to use later. I want to reach this lists first member. I tried

```
     Point p1 = ucgen[0];
```

but this is wrong. How can I reach it ?
r

Comment: The stuff outside of the class scope doesn't make sense.  Is it in another class, does it need to be in a method?

Comment: Your question is not completed and understandable, please edit it.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, it's in a method. I forgot to write. I will edit

Comment: Adem abi yardım edebilir misin burdan türkçe yazsam ingilizce yazmak zor oluyor

Comment: I glad to see your problem is solved :)

Comment: Adem abi I'm glad olacak o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making some assumptions about how your code is structured (the code in the question as it stands is not very helpful), I would say the problem is that you are getting a `DrawAction` from the list and trying to assign it to a `Point`.

The simplest answer would be to do:

```
PointF p1 = ucgen[0].Koordinat;
```

or perhaps

```
DrawAction d1 = ucgen[0];
```

Note also that your `DrawAction` class uses a `PointF`, but you seem to be trying to get a `Point` out.  Either change the type of the variable in the code (as I have done) or cast `PointF` to `Point` (with loss of precision) if that is what you intend.

However, I must point out that blindly accessing element 0 without testing this is going to cause problems when the list is empty.  Without knowing more of the code I wouldn't be able to make a firm recommendation, except to suggest `foreach`, or the Linq `FirstOrDefault()` as suggested by user9190331.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you haven’t done something wrong, like @Felix Castor said, you can always use FirstOrDefault:

```
var test = YourList.FirstOrDefault();
```